# Rails: setting parameters in URLs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

I have a route like `get "/schools/:id/:sport_name" => "schools#show"`, but when I run `school_path(School.first, sport_name: "football")`, the route generated is `http://localhost:3000/schools/slug-name-here?sport_name=football`...

I thought you could pass in the matched parameter name and the URL generator would build the URL based on the options set. May just be having a "case of the mondays", but I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: school_path(School.first, 'football', other_options:'here')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to simply do:

```
school_path([School.first, 'football'])
```

Any other `params` you add at the end like so:

```
school_path([School.first, 'football'], foo: :bar)
```

Will be passed as `http://localhost:3000/schools/football?foo=bar`

Comment: Try: `school_path([School.first, 'football'])`